# Oracle Apex: Is it possible to create buttons which have similar functionality to the action menu within interactive reports?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

This is in oracle apex 4.2. I am in the interactive reports region and need to be able to 'select which columns within the report', 'Filter the rows', 'download the report', 'reset the report'. The action menu does all of this (And I can limit just to these options), but that format isn't as user friendly as 4 separate buttons. Would it be possible to put the functionality mentioned above into separate buttons or even modify the action menu to appear as buttons rather than in a menu? Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks

P.S. I would like to just have the action menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the functionality of the action menu is performed by javascript actions which you could easily assign to buttons of your own making.  The Filter Rows action uses this javascript: `javascript:gReport.dialog2('SHOW_FILTER');` as it's action (href attribute value) whereas the download action uses this: `javascript:gReport.dialog2('SHOW_DOWNLOAD');`

You should be able to inspect the HTML for each of the action menu items of interest and create buttons using the same scripts.

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect.

Comment: @Chris This works, but is really unsupported. Once you move to 5 it's broken and that's the end of it. I'd refrain from using the `gReport` variable unless you really have to. Honestly, just live with it. You're altering core functionality while this is more a matter of educating your users. If you feel this is crucial functionality then add it as a feature request. Unless you feel like adding in more hacks later down the line is interesting.